# how can avoid to execute a function with annotations or interceptor?

Tags: java, android

I want to try an annotation that checks if the user is logged in, and for doing this I want to create `@onLogged` annotation . The idea is that if the user is not logged in, the function doesn't execute.

I try the next example or similar, but I don't have access to the function to avoid its execution for example with this I cannot the callable of `aaa` and cancel the execution:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
public @interface MethodInfo {
    String author() default "Igor Brishkoski";
    int revision() default 1;
    String comments();
}


@MethodInfo(author = "John Snow", revision = 2, comments = "Hey!")
    public void aaa(){
        try {
            Method method = getClass().getMethod("aaa");
            MethodInfo methodInfo = method.getAnnotation(MethodInfo.class);

            Log.d("MethodInfo", methodInfo.author());
            Log.d("MethodInfo", methodInfo.comments());
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("MethodInfo", "Error");
        }
    }
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks